# Rspec should change count without lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, shoulda

I am trying to figure out another way of writing the should change count test (without lambda).
I am using Rails 3. I am also utilizing the shoulda matcher gem

Reason - All test cases are in the format

```
describe "some stuff" do
   it { should ... }
 end
```

But I am not able to follow the same pattern for testing the should change count

Here is what I have

```
describe "some stuff" do
    it "should change count by one" do 
        lambda { ... }.should change(Model, :count).by(1)
    end 
end
```

Is there a way to write it

```
describe "some stuff" do
   it { should change(Model, :count).by(1) }
 end
```

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
subject { lambda { ... } }

it { should change(Model, :count).by(1) }
```

Comment: I was writing specs like this for a while and actually trying to find a more concise way to do this. Is this the best possible option?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the expect syntax:

```
describe "some stuff" do
  expect { ... }.to change(Model, :count).by(1)
end
```